# Retry Logic in case of failure - Spring Reactor

Tags: spring, project-reactor

How do i unit test RetryWhen,

```
 public Mono<List<Transaction>> get(String id) {
            return class
                    .get(id).log()
                 .retryWhen(throwableFlux -> throwableFlux) 
                .zipWith(Flux.range(min, max + 1), (error, retry) -> new RetryException(error, retry))
                .flatMap(retryException -> {
                    if(retryException.getRetries() == max + 1) {
                        throw Exceptions.propagate(retryException.getThrowable());
                    } else if (isClientException(retryException.getThrowable())){
                        return Flux.empty();
                    }
                    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofMinutes( new Double(multiplier * retryException.getRetries()).longValue()));
                }));
        }
```

How do i use StepVerifier to test this method?

Another way to implement retry logic,

```
throwableFlux.takeWhile(throwable -> !isClientException(throwable))
            .flatMap(e -> {
                if(count.get() >= max + 1) {
                    throw Exceptions.propagate(e);
                }
                LOG.info("Retrying in..");
                return Mono.delay(Duration.ofMinutes(new Double(multiplier * count.getAndAdd(1)).longValue()));
            });
```

Comment: isn't there an additional closing parenthesis on the `retryWhen` line? you are applying the zipWith.flatMap to `throwableFlux`, right?

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean testing the `RetryHelper` applied through `retryWhen`?

You can certainly use `StepVerifier` to test such a retryWhen containing sequence, yes. You can also check the number of (re)subscriptions by using an `AtomicLong` coupled to a `doOnSubscribe` just before the `retryWhen` (it will help assert the number of subscriptions made to the source being retried).

Note that we just added such a builder utility for `retryWhen`and `repeatWhen`, but in the [`reactor-extra` project](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/commit/10ccb0ff7d72cc441f4460e702b1ebf9c42bacf6) (currently in 3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

Comment: oops. i just expanded the code. i was able to test my code with stepverifier.withVirtualTime. Im returning a Flux.empty() - (no-op) for a certain condition. Is there a recommendation as to how to test that?

Comment: testing an empty but finite flux is as easy as `verifyComplete()` with no previous expectation short of `expectSubscription`

Comment: FirstStep.verifyComplete()  or         type.expectSubscription().verifyComplete() both get stuck in an infinite for loop in DefaultStepVerifierBuilder.pollTaskEventOrComplete.

Comment: ah my bad if you're using virtual time you probably still need to advance the clock via `thenAwait` or `expectNoEvent` (I suppose you added delays and retries in your chain, which just happens to end up empty due to other operators?)

Comment: yes. thats correct. because if was not advancing the clock on a certain type of error, i was not calling expectNoEvent. thank you.

Comment: btw, i was able to implement an alternative way to apply retry logic. i have updated my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how i was able to test this code.

```
FirstStep.expectSubscription().expectNoEvent(java.time.Duration.ofMinutes(1)).expectNoEvent(Duration.ofMinutes(3)).verifyError()
```

> We could have used thenAwait(Duration.ofDays(1)) above, but
>   expectNoEvent has the benefit of guaranteeing that nothing happened
>   earlier that it should have.
>
> http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/snapshot/reference/docs/index.html#error.handling